# SEO tips for blog posts pagination

Tags: url, pagination, seo, blog, google-index

Three years ago we launched a self-made blog area on our e-commerce website. 
Call it an *experimental feature*, if you know what I mean.

We had, and still have, a very minimalistic URL schema:

```
/blog/2016/04/27/todays-blog-post/ -> a post. 
/blog/ -> the archive of ALL posts in the blog, since 2013.
```

Nowadays, we have hundreds of posts, all in one page (the archive), and that's a very slow and non-scalable area of the website: a very bad design choice isn't it?

Nevertheless, Google indexer seems to really appreciate our blog archive page, its ranking in search results is always very good! So, we don't want to lose even a little of all that goodness!

Anyway, we can't leave that page growing larger, so we did some refactoring to introduce a simple blog-style pagination, using the typical [older posts / newer posts] links, pointing to a new URL schema:

```
/blog -> page1
/blog/p/2/ -> page2
/blog/p/3/ -> page3
```

My first question is: **how Google will treat** (or it's likely to) **our change?**

The second one: **is that a good URL schema for such purpose? Is that SEO-friendly enough?** (maybe it would be better to put the page number as a query parameter, instead of using a REST path?)